# Reading "Model Collation" for a deployed SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vsdbcmd

We are using database projects to deploy our databases. In the project settings, we have specific a Project Version (version of target SQL Server) and a Collation for Data model.

However, when I deploy it, I get the following error

```
    TSD00560    The project and target databases have different collation settings. Deployment errors might occur.
```

This happens when we are deploying in upgrade mode. My question is, is there any way to read Model Collation from a deployed database?

We are using VSDBCMD for deployment

Comment: `SELECT DataBasePropertyEx('model', 'collation') As collation_of_model_database`

Comment: Not sure if this is what I was after. Need to get the model collation set in the database property. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/10/04/model-collation-vs-database-collation.aspx.

Comment: Wondering if there is a property in database for it at all or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VSDBCMD to generate the model from the database using:

vsdbcmd.exe /Action:Import

In the schema file (output) you got a tag named DataSchemaModel that has a property called CollationLcid that displays the model setting of the target database.

I do not know any property on the target database you can retrieve, maybe this can be done using the Microsoft schema libs.